# Repairing MySQL databases - restoring data issue

Tags: mysql, backup, database

Today I reinstalled [Web-Developer Server Suite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webdeveloper/) and although all my old PHP pages work, the databases don't... I copied them over from my backup folder and only some of the tables re-appeared.

How would I restore all data in the databases: when I look in phpMyAdmin some are missing or incomplete.

It's the first, and hopefully, last time I'll have to do such a thing... how should I handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I have always restored a previous instance by copying the whole $PATH/lib/mysql/data folder to the new instance. Just ensure that the folder is owned by the new MySQL instance and everything should launch OK.

Comment: I did this; but one of my databases - mytvguide - has problems, some of the tables didn't re-appear when I did this.

Comment: When I had tables or schema missing it was because some sub folders were still owned/readable by the old user.